# Can't change the value inside input

Tags: reactjs, firebase, input, react-redux, controlled-component

I'm trying to change the values inside inputs. I got those values from the db.
But it doesn't allow me to type or edit the value.
I've added an `handleInputChange` function to put inside `onChange` inside each input tag but it didn't work.
I need those values to be inside inputs at the beginning and disappear after the user starts typing.

I thought about `ref={ref}` and `defaultValue`, but I don't know how I'll get updated values than in order to send it back to the db.

EditFeedbackPage.js

```
    const EditFeedbackPage = () => {
    
        const initialState = {
            category: "All",
            comments: [],
            detail: "",
            id: nanoid(),
            createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
            status: "Suggestion",
            title: "",
            upVotesCount: []
        }
    
        const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
        const { feedback } = useSelector((state) => state.data);
    
        const { category, detail, title, status } = feedback;
        console.log(feedback)
    
        const params = useParams();
        const { id } = params;
        console.log("id from params => ", id)
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
        const navigate = useNavigate();
    
        const cancelAddFeedback = () => {
            navigate("/")
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(getSingleFeedback(id));
            console.log("feedbackId => ", id);
    
        }, []);
    
        const editFeedback = async (e, id) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("feedbackId => ", id);
            dispatch(editFeedbackInit(id, feedback))
        }
    
        const handleInputChange = (e) => {
            let { name, value } = e.target;
            setState({ ...state, [name]: value })
        }
    
        const handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            setState({ ...state, title: '', detail: "", category: "All" })
        }

        return (

                    <EditFeedbackFormContainer
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        <h4>Feedback Title</h4>
                        <label htmlFor="title">Add a short, descriptive headline</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name='title'
                            value={title}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}

                        />

                        <h4>Category</h4>
                        <label htmlFor="category">Change a category for your feedback</label>
                        <select
                            name="category"
                            id="category"
                            value={category}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        >
                            <option value="All">All</option>
                            <option value="UI">UI</option>
                            <option value="UX">UX</option>
                            <option value="Enhancement">Enhancement</option>
                            <option value="Bug">Bug</option>
                            <option value="Feature">Feature</option>
                        </select>

                        <h4>Update Status</h4>
                        <label htmlFor="status">Change feedback status</label>
                        <select
                            name="status"
                            id="status"
                            value={status}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        >
                            <option value="Suggestion">Suggestion</option>
                            <option value="Planned">Planned</option>
                            <option value="In-Progress">In-Progress</option>
                            <option value="Live">Live</option>
                        </select>

                        <h4>Change a feedback detail</h4>
                        <label htmlFor="detail">Include any specific comments on what should be improved, added, etc.</label>
                        <textarea
                            name="detail"
                            id="detail"
                            value={detail}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}

                        />
                        <EditFeedbackButtonsContainer>
                            <EditFeedbackButtonDelete
                                onClick={deleteFeedback}
                            >
                                Delete
                            </EditFeedbackButtonDelete>

                            <EditFeedbackButtonCancel onClick={cancelAddFeedback}>Cancel</EditFeedbackButtonCancel>
                            <EditFeedbackButtonAdd
                                onClick={editFeedback}
                            >Edit Feedback</EditFeedbackButtonAdd>
                        </EditFeedbackButtonsContainer>
                    </EditFeedbackFormContainer>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data structure, you can give your inputs a name & let the other state data same and update only one input.

```
import { Container, TextField, Stack, MenuItem, Button } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";

const EditFeedbackPage = () => {
  const initialState = {
    category: "All",
    comments: [],
    detail: "Test",
    id: uuidV4(),
    createdAt: new Date(),
    status: "Suggestion",
    title: "",
    upVotesCount: []
  };

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(JSON.stringify(state, null, 2));
  };

  return (
    <Container
      sx={{
        mt: 2
      }}
    >
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <TextField
          size="small"
          name="title"
          value={state.title}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          label="Add a short, descriptive headline"
        />
        <TextField
          select
          size="small"
          name="category"
          value={state.category}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          label="Change a category for your feedback"
        >
          <MenuItem value="All">All</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="UI">UI</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="UX">UX</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Enhancement">Enhancement</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Bug">Bug</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Feature">Feature</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
        <TextField
          select
          size="small"
          name="status"
          id="status"
          value={state.status}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          label="Change feedback status"
        >
          <MenuItem value="Suggestion">Suggestion</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Planned">Planned</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="In-Progress">In-Progress</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="Live">Live</MenuItem>
        </TextField>
        <TextField
          multiline
          rows={4}
          size="small"
          name="detail"
          value={state.detail}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          label="Include any specific comments on what should be improved, added, etc."
        />
      </Stack>
      <Button
        sx={{
          mt: 2
        }}
        onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Submit
      </Button>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default EditFeedbackPage;
```

Comment: Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-cartwright-jy53rf?file=/src/Root.js

Answer (score 1):

use the `state` value in the title

```
  <input
          type="text"
          name='title'
          value={state.title}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
  />
```

And assign useSelector value to initial state

```
    const { feedback } = useSelector((state) => state.data);

    const { category, detail, title, status } = feedback;
    console.log(feedback)
   
    const initialState = {
        category: "All",
        comments: [],
        detail: "",
        id: nanoid(),
        createdAt: Timestamp.now().toDate(),
        status: "Suggestion",
        title,
        upVotesCount: []
    }

    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
```